# Windows Server 2008 R2 change domain

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory

I ran whoami on a power console and it said that my domain was "mycomputername/username"  (mycomputername = the actual computer name)

Anyhow how do I change it so it displays my domain/username

Thanks

Comment: Has the server been joined to the domain? When you log in, are you entering the domain name either before or after the username? Domain usernames can be entered as either `domain\user` or `user@domain`.

Answer (score 7):

Sign into the computer with a domain account.

Comment: you can't ... it signs me in automatically as computername/administrator

Comment: Well then fix it. You're the sysadmin, right?

Comment: @Steven disable automatic logon

Comment: @Steven I'd bet you two puppies and a pancake breakfast that ErikA acually *can* switch to a domain user account. I think you meant to say "*I* can't." Have you tried "log out" and/or "switch user"?